# Absolute position is causing text to skew right

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a link that I'm trying to `position:absolute` inside a `position:relative` container. However when I do so, it skews the text to the right by about 10-15pxs and makes it look really off center. However if I change absolute to relative, the text returns to where it should be (the center). Why is position:absolute doing this, and is there any fixes? I've included my code below and any help would be great. Thanks!

The text that is giving me trouble is this:

```
        <div class="green select">

            <p><a class="button" href="links/calculator.html">Discover</a></p>

        </div>

    </div>
```

Here is the rest of my HTML:

```css
.headerContent {
  position: relative;
  width: 55%;
  margin: auto;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.title {
  font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: white;
  font-size: 90px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.headerText {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 35%;
  font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 27px;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.select a {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  top: 225px;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 110px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  margin: auto;
}

.select a::before,
.select a::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  content: '';
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
  transition: transform 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
}

.select a::after {
  border-color: #fff;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-7px) translateX(6px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-7px) translateX(6px);
  transform: translateY(-7px) translateX(6px);
}

.select a:hover::before,
.select a:focus::before {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(5px) translateX(-5px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(5px) translateX(-5px);
  transform: translateY(5px) translateX(-5px);
}

.select a:hover::after,
.select a:focus::after {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0px) translateX(0px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(0px) translateX(0px);
  transform: translateY(0px) translateX(0px);
}
```

```html
<div class="headerContent">

  <nav>

    <ul class="navDown">
      <li><a href="#">Intro</a></li>
      <li><a href="#windSection">Wind</a></li>
      <li><a href="#solarSection">Solar</a></li>
      <li><a href="#nuclearSection">Nuclear</a></li>
      <li><a href="#endSection">End</a></li>
    </ul>

    <a href="#" class="menu-icon">
      <p class="menu"></p>
    </a>

  </nav>

  <a href="#" class="scrollup">Scroll</a>
  <a href="#windSection" id="scrolldown">Scroll</a>

  <h1 class="title bigTitle">Going Green.</h1>

  <p class="headerText">
    A change is coming- and that change will be making the switch to green forms of energy. If you are interested in learning how you can help the environment and save money over time- you have come to the right place. It is time to Energize Change. <br>
    <span
      class="emphasis">Click below to find the perfect green energy source for you and your family!</span>
  </p>

  <img class="people" src="images/peoplesSad.png" />
  <p class="noElechouse"></p>
  <div class="green select">
    <p><a class="button" href="links/calculator.html">Discover</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: .green is position relative? When you position absolute something, it is removed from the normal flow and maybe this is the reason why the text moves to the right. Maybe a link would help us..

Comment: http://energizechange.com/  the discover button looks positioned normally but i set that there manually

Comment: Why you have position:absolute everything? You have to do a lot of changes. Why headerText or the images in header is positioned absolute? And you can't have a <p> inside a link..it's block element in an inline element.

Comment: oh the p and a was my fault I was trying something out. I usually relative position the wrapper and position absoulte inside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
.select a
{
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
```

Honestly I don't see why you're bent on absolutely positioning your link.
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jt4f4/)

Answer (score 0):

The containing block, which is the first ancestor element that does not have position: static. If there is no such ancestor, the  element serves as the containing block.

you can do it that way

add

```
.relative {position: relative !important}
```

and append it to

```
<a class="button relative" href="links/calculator.html">Discover</a>
```

Comment: Why should he position relative the link, since he wants it position absolute? :P

Comment: If positon is absolute it's moved from the normal object flow and other objects will change position and will move into the space this object once occupied. The absolute class allows you to place the object in front of or behind other objects so in that case I would use relative else if the positon is absolute I would position it in exact location on the page.

Comment: I have to position it absoulte sorry!